# Determine ajax request from my server

Tags: php, ajax

is it possible to determine the server from which ajax request is send??,
and if yes then how could i determine and execute only those requests which are from my server..

Answer (score 3):

aeh, you're mixing server/client stuff (like so many others). i could misinterpret your question in 3 ways:

1. **unfunny joke**
   it's possible to determine the server serving the ajax response. if the request goes to `http://www.example.com/foo.bar?id=boo`, the serving servers name may be `www.example.com` (unless you're the victim of DNS hijacking).
2. **possible, but improbable**
   if you want your server to response only to your personal client (=browser), then filter by ip. if you got a static ip. and maybe authentication over a secure connection.
3. **most likley**
   if you want to serve ajax requests from your server only to sites originating from your server, you have to do authentication (via basic auth or sessions).

Comment: 1 is not so unfunny )). 3 is really most likely and basic auth imho is the best and the most simple for this case.